# htaccess 301 redirect subdirectory but not anything inside the subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have technically two subdirectories. /products/industry/

I'd like to redirect as follows:

```
/products/industry to /products/#industry
```

However I don't want to redirect something like:

```
/products/industry/product-name
```

Or anything that might follow /industry. Here's what I had in my htaccess that wasn't working. Maybe I'm close?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/industry[/]?$
RewriteRule (.*) /products/#industry [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bti/

RewriteRule ^(products)/(industry)$ $1/#$2 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: In my test this redirected `/products/industry` to `/products/#industry` Can you make sure to keep this rule as 1st rule and try this in a new browser.

Comment: I modified it to use a subdirectory. I still get no results in multiple browsers and cleared cache. 
RewriteRule ^(bti)/(products)/(industry)$ /$1/$2/#$3 [R=301,L,NE,NC]

Comment: Is this placed in a subdirectory called `/bti/`?

Comment: Of course. My whole site is the the /bti subdirectory.

Comment: Of course you didn't mention it any where in question